# DB monitoring on NewRelic with rubyagent on ECS Fargate with Aurora serverless (PGSQL) not working

Tags: amazon-ecs, newrelic, aws-aurora-serverless

We’re using the New Relic rubyagent gem to monitor a rails 6.0 app, deployed on AWS ECS using RDS Serverless PGSQL as a database. However, the DB does not show up under external services or databases in New Relic. I'd like to monitor for slow transactions using New Relic's features around that. Any suggestion what is happening here?

`config/newrelic.yml:`

```
common: &default_settings
  license_key: <%= ENV['NEWRELIC_LICENSE_KEY'] %>
  agent_enabled: auto
  app_name: my_app
  monitor_mode: true
  developer_mode: false
  log_level: info

  attributes:
    include: job.sidekiq.args.*

  browser_monitoring:
      auto_instrument: false

  audit_log:
    enabled: false

  transaction_tracer:
    enabled: true
    transaction_threshold: apdex_f
    record_sql: raw
    stack_trace_threshold: 0.500
    explain_enabled: false

  error_collector:
    enabled: true
    capture_source: true
    ignore_errors: "ActionController::RoutingError,Sinatra::NotFound,ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,CGI::Session::CookieStore::TamperedWithCookie,ActionController::UnknownAction,AbstractController::ActionNotFound,Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound,Sinatra::NotFound,Sidekiq::Limiter::OverLimit"


development:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: false
  developer_mode: true

test:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: false

production:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The New Relic Ruby agent and all the agents New Relic puts out there (background information I'm a 7 year New Relic employee who is a Product Manager for the APM UI but not the agent itself) have instrumentation built into them that if you query databases using specific libraries that the Ruby Agent supports, we track and time those interactions and in the case of Databases trace slow SQL, request explain plans etc.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/ruby-agent/getting-started/ruby-agent-requirements-supported-frameworks/#databases

The Ruby agent has a number of libraries it supports for Database interaction. Pull enhanced instance details when using specific versions

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/ruby-agent/getting-started/ruby-agent-requirements-supported-frameworks/#instance_details

and for external HTTP requests (that aren't instrumented database requests that use these libraries

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/ruby-agent/getting-started/ruby-agent-requirements-supported-frameworks/#http_clients

We show in the Externals section. This might help clarify why it's not appearing as expected. My best guess is you're using a library that NR currently doesn't instrument.

If I'm wrong and it's listed. Absolutely file a support ticket for our Tech Support team to investigate and if it's not listed, you can talk to your sales person if you're working for a company paying for NR to file a feature request to suggest support for such a library that you are using.

Also New Relic open sources our agents these days so if you wanted to write instrumentation for your preferred library and submit it you can find the agent code here

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent

Hope that's helpful